# Can only access asp.net app on the server

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm trying to get an asp.net application set up on IIS on a Windows Server 2008 machine. I can hit the app from localhost, no problem. I can access the app using the server's domain name locally on the server but not from another machine on the network.

when trying to access the application from another PC across the network it just times out and and says

"The server at x.xxx.x.xxx is taking too long to respond"

```
http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:[some port number]/MyApplicationWebAppName
```

Looking at the event log I'm getting the following errors? I've goggled these and its talking about sharepoint which is installed on the server but this shouldn;t stop me being able to access the app across the network

> WebHost failed to process a request.
>    Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/33711845
>    Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The farm is unavailable.

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue. Do you know if your network allows HTTP traffic to flow inside of it?

Comment: Not 100% sure how would I check?

Comment: Ok cool I've just found thats the issue, thanks for the pointer :-) If you post it as an answer I will accept it, it was the sharepoint permission on the firewall which were the issue, HTTP traffic was allowed

Comment: Glad that helped! Reposting it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a firewall issue. Do you know if your network allows HTTP traffic to flow inside of it?